# Nth value of Function

Tags: functions, algorithms

Given x and y we define a function as follow :

```
f(1)=x
f(2)=y
f(i)=f(i-1) + f(i+1) for i>2
```

Now given x and y, how to calculate f(n)

Example : If x=2 and y=3 and n=3 then answer is 1

as f(2) = f(1) + f(3), 3 = 2 + f(3), f(3) = 1.

Constraints are : x,y,n all can go upto 10^9.

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Comment: May I ask what you obtained ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah see the function is periodic after every 6 terms..:)

Comment: Congratulations : this perfectly correct.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah see : 
x-y,x,y,y-x,-x,-y

Comment: Bingo ! What is $f(123456789)$ ? Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Just calculate its remainder when divided by 6 and then find corresponding value from mentioned 6 terms

Comment: Congratulations for your good work and understanding and answering my stupid questions. Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Your welcome..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the first dozen numbers.  You should find a simple result for this algorithm.

Comment: Am not able to get it..:(

Comment: Your formula says that $f(i+1)=f(i)-f(i-1)$.  So each term is the previous term, minus the one before that.  The third term is y-x.  The sequence starts x,y,y-x.  Now what is the third term minus the second term?  Continue like that.

Comment: Thanx..it worked..:)

Answer (score 0):

The general way to solve $$F(i+1)= F(i) - F(i - 1)$$
Is to first to see that if $F(i + 1)$ can be written as the sum of 2 geometric series, so that $$F(n) = ar^n + bs^n$$
So $$ar^{n+1} + bs^{n+1} = ar^{n} + bs^n - ar^{n-1} - bs^{n-1}$$
 $$ar^{n-1}(1 - r + r^2) = -bs^{n-1}(1 - s + s^2)$$

Since $r\ne s$, it follows that both $r$ and $s$ must satisfy the quadratic equation $$1-x+x^2 = 0$$
So $$r = \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2}, s = \frac{1 - \sqrt{3}i}{2}$$
Now we find $a$ and $b$, using $F(1)$ and $F(2)$
$$F(1) = x = a\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^1 + b\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^1$$
$$F(2) = y = a\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^2 + b\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^2$$
And then you find the closed form of your recurrence series.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int n,int x,int y){
     if (n==1) return x;
     else if (n==2) return y;
     else return fib(n-1,x,y) + fib(n-2,x,y);
}

int main()
{
   int x,y,n,z;
   printf("Give a value for x:");
   scanf("%d",&x);
   printf("Give a value for y:");
   scanf("%d",&y);
   printf("Give a value for n:");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   z=fib(n,x,y);
   printf("The result is: %d",z);
}
```

Comment: “Dont give a child a fish but show him how to fish” as Mao Tse-tung said. I suppose that the OP is looking for the general formula in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: The recurrence is NOT Fibonacci.